# iframe not appearing on product page (not WYSIWYG related)

Tags: magento, iframe

First of all I just want to clarify that this is NOT related to the WYSIWYG CMS editor problem that a lot of people have, what I am trying to do is include an iframe in part of a product listing (for simplicity sake lets say in the description, because the function is the same as where I'm actually trying to put it).  The code does not disappear when saved (like it does before the WYSIWYG CMS fix), but then nothing is displayed on the product page - is there something that needs to be changed to allow it to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You say in a product listing... I am not sure if you mean in the list.phtml template (category) or the view.phtml template (product page).

I recommend you double check the attribute's settings you are trying to display.

Go to Catalog > Attribute > Select Attribute > Properties > Frontend Properties

Enable WYSIWYG > No

Allow HTML Tags on Frontend > Yes

Visible on Product View Page on Front-end > Yes

Used in Product Listing > Yes

Double check that no CSS rule may be causing the issue, either.

Comment: view.phtml, the individual product page - I should have clarified, the same attribute is used to display youtube videos using <object> tags and that works fine - what sort of CSS ruling could cause it?